# Can we skip zoom animation for a particular item in ListRowPresenter - Leanback Android TV

Tags: android-tv, leanback

I would like to cancel the zoom animation for the first element only. Is there any way to do it.

I initialise
ListRowPresenter(FocusHighlight.ZOOM_FACTOR_LARGE, false) like this

But the zoom animation applies to all the element in the row. Is there any way to not apply this zoom animation for a single content ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created two presenters and added zoom factor in one of the presenter on the focus listener.

Answer (score 0):

Create fractions.xml in res folder->values to override the Leanback layout:
Make the Zoom to 100% indicates the Original Size
//fractions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item name="lb_focus_zoom_factor_xsmall" type="fraction" 
 tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource">
    100%
</item>
</resources>
```

[image]